# Map coordinate ids to coordinate values

Tags: python-3.x, list, dataframe, mapping, numpy-ndarray

I have a list of coordinate ids (nodes of a graph).

```
edge_list = 
[(0, 1),
 (2, 3),
 (4, 3)]
```

And the coordinates of these nodes are stored in a nd numpy array

```
position =
array([[[ -3.17113447, -16.9386692 ,  16.73578644],
        [  8.19985676,   4.89544773,  21.26950455]],

       [[ -8.96962166,  -2.78070927,  54.1053009 ],
        [ -0.1561521 ,  -3.05777478,  41.8996582 ]],

       [[-13.20408821,  -4.88086224,  46.99597549],
        [ -0.1561521 ,  -3.05777478,  41.8996582 ]]], dtype=float32)
```

The above data is not easy to access and has duplicates. I want to transform it to the following format

```
df = 
node  x             y            z
0    -3.17113447 -16.9386692   16.73578644
1     8.19985676  4.89544773   21.26950455
2    -8.96962166  -2.78070927  54.1053009 
3    -0.1561521  -3.05777478   41.8996582 
4    -13.20408821  -4.88086224  46.99597549
```

To obtain the above dataframe, I first tried to convert the coordinates in `position` to a dictionary

```
for i in range(len(edge_list)):
        map[f'edge{i}'] = position[0]

 {'edge0': array([[ -3.17113447, -16.9386692 ,  16.73578644],
       [  8.19985676,   4.89544773,  21.26950455]], dtype=float32),
 'edge1': array([[ -3.17113447, -16.9386692 ,  16.73578644],
       [  8.19985676,   4.89544773,  21.26950455]], dtype=float32),
 'edge3': array([[ -3.17113447, -16.9386692 ,  16.73578644],
       [  8.19985676,   4.89544773,  21.26950455]], dtype=float32)}
```

I'm not really sure how to proceed from here.

Any suggestions will be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can map your edges to a single, unique number in the following way. If you have N nodes, think of an edge as an element on a (N by N) array. And mapping position (i,j) to a single number is a very classic trick. In your case, the unique index is index = i*N+j.